# How to generate same random values in php if they have same parameter?

Tags: php

I'm using a function to generate random values using TAG including parameters as Length, type of random : Alphabetic, Numeric or Mix, and LowerCase, Uppercase.
Now this issue is that I want to store or save, fix or freeze, a random result to use it in multiples places. 
For exemple instead of RAND, I use FixRAND, then the result will be the same in the whole page as long as TAG have the same parameters.

To give you a small idea of what I already have. It's fully functional when I use some TAGs Like [RAND,10,A,U] but It generate random values every time. I need to add another TAG that can store some how the same results upon the same request.

```
function generateRandom($length,$type,$gen){
        switch ($type) {
            case 'A':
                $rd= "";
                srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
                $data = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
                for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
                    $rd .= substr($data, (rand()%(strlen($data))), 1);
                }
                break;
            case 'N':
                $rd= "";
                srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
                $data = '0123456789';
                for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
                    $rd .= substr($data, (rand()%(strlen($data))), 1);
                }
                break;
            case 'M':
                $rd= "";
                srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
                $data = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789";
                for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
                    $rd .= substr($data, (rand()%(strlen($data))), 1);
                }

                break;
        }
        if ( $gen == 'U') $rd = strtoupper($rd);
        if ( $gen == 'L') $rd = strtolower($rd);
        return $rd;
    }

$replaced_xxxxxx=str_replace("[MESSAGE]","$message",$replaced_xxxxxx);
preg_match_all("/\[RAND,[0-9]+,[AMN],[LU]\]/",$replaced_xxxxxx,$random_tag_array);
        foreach ($random_tag_array[0] as $random_tag) {
            $random_stripped=$random_tag;
            $random_stripped=str_replace("[RAND,","",$random_stripped);
            $random_stripped=str_replace("]","",$random_stripped);
            $random_exploded=explode(',', $random_stripped);
            $random_generated=generateRandom($random_exploded[0],$random_exploded[1],$random_exploded[2]);
            $replaced_xxxxxx=preg_replace($random_tag, $random_generated, $replaced_xxxxxx,1);
```

Comment: It won't be very random if it is the same. I think you're very confused. Either something is random, or not. It's not that difficult. If you're looking for something that **looks random** but isn't really, you could use [hashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). Most hashes stay the same when the input stays the same. Another way to use the same real random number sereral times is to store it (cookie, sesssion, database).

Comment: Hashes is a good idea, but I'm generating not only this once, with the same parameters, I need thousand of result in the same time, so if very result it must be different. So it a random that's fixed only in one result.

Comment: Guaranteeing that some random number is actually really unique is quite difficult. Even the build-in function [uniqid()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) warns you about this, and its whole purpose is to generate an unique id.

Comment: I feel kind of ignored. Doesn't my answer work? Is it not what you are trying? Can you give any feedback please?

Comment: @user11209806 ok :) I was just a bit irritated because you were answering to everyone except me :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As @KIKOSoftware points out, my answer was *not real random*. I modified my answer. This now uses [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.random-int.php) which cryptographically secure pseudo-random. The results of the random function are now saved together with the input parameters. This is the only way because `random_int()` *is* random. This way there is no way to create the same values again so they have to be saved.

This solution takes more memory because it needs to save more values. But this one is random. You may choose between both solutions. If you are trying to get random examples the original solution is enough. For things that need to be secure (e.g. password handling ect.) you should use the new solution.

**Note: Requires PHP 7+**. If you are working with a lower version there is a backporting function on [php.net in the comments](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.random-int.php#119670).

```
function generateRandom($length, $type, $gen){
    switch ($type){
        case 'A':
            $data = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
            break;
        case 'N':
            $data = '0123456789';
            break;
        case 'M':
            $data = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789";
            break;
        default: 
            $data = "";
            break;
    }

    static $randoms = array();

    $rd = "";
    $max = strlen($data) - 1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $rd_key = $length.$type.$gen.$i;
        if(!isset($randoms[$rd_key])){
            $randoms[$rd_key] = random_int(0, $max);
        }
        $rd .= $data[$randoms[$rd_key]];
    }

    if ( $gen == 'U') $rd = strtoupper($rd);
    if ( $gen == 'L') $rd = strtolower($rd);

    return $rd;
}
```

Example Result

[image]

Generated with code:

```
print("<table>".
        "<tr>".
            "<th>Function</th>".
            "<th>Secure result</th>".
            "<th>Secure is correct</th>".
            "<th>Normal result</th>".
            "<th>Normal is correct</th>".
        "</tr>");
$cache_normal = array();
$cache_secure = array();
// 12 possibilities, there has to be one double element
for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++){
    $length = rand(3, 5);
    $type = rand(0, 2);
    switch($type){
        case 1: $type = "N"; break;
        case 2: $type = "M"; break;
        case 0: 
        default: $type = "A"; break;
    }
    $gen = rand(0, 1);
    switch($gen){
        case 1: $gen = "U"; break;
        case 0: 
        default: $gen = "L"; break;
    }

    $secure = generateRandomSecure($length, $type, $gen);

    if(!isset($cache_secure[$length.$type.$gen])){
        $cache_secure[$length.$type.$gen] = $secure;
        $secure_corr = "-";
    }
    elseif($cache_secure[$length.$type.$gen] == $secure){
        $secure_corr = "<i>found and correct</i>";
    }
    else{
        $secure_corr = "<i>found but wrong</i>";
    }

    $normal = generateRandom($length, $type, $gen);
    if(!isset($cache_normal[$length.$type.$gen])){
        $cache_normal[$length.$type.$gen] = $normal;
        $normal_corr = "-";
    }
    elseif($cache_normal[$length.$type.$gen] == $normal){
        $normal_corr = "<i>found and correct</i>";
    }
    else{
        $normal_corr = "<i>found but wrong</i>";
    }

    print("<tr>".
            "<td><code>generateRandom(".$length.", ".$type.", ". $gen.")</code></td>".
            "<td>'".$secure."'</td>".
            "<td>".$secure_corr."</td>".
            "<td>'".$normal."'</td>".
            "<td>".$normal_corr."</td>".
        "</tr>"
    );
}
print("</table>");
```

---

**Original answer**: I think I would store the seed of the random. You can use a static (or global) variable which contains the parameters as the keys and the seed as the value.

```
function generateRandom($length, $type, $gen){
    static $seeds = array();
    if(!isset($seeds[$length.$type.$gen])){
        $seeds[$length.$type.$gen] = microtime(true) * 1000000;
    }
    srand($seeds[$length.$type.$gen]);
    $rd = "";

    switch ($type) {
        case 'A':
            $data = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
            break;
        case 'N':
            $data = '0123456789';
            break;
        case 'M':
            $data = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789";
            break;
        default: 
            $data = "";
            break;
    }

    $len = strlen($data);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
       $rd .= $data[rand() % $len];
    }

    if ( $gen == 'U') $rd = strtoupper($rd);
    if ( $gen == 'L') $rd = strtolower($rd);

    return $rd;
}
```

This code results in the following. I hope this is what you are trying to do:

```
var_dump(generateRandom(3, "A", "L")); // prints e.g. string(3) "wkr"
var_dump(generateRandom(4, "A", "L")); // prints e.g. string(3) "rppd"
var_dump(generateRandom(4, "N", "L")); // prints string(4) "9377"
var_dump(generateRandom(3, "A", "L")); // prints string(3) "wkr" again
```

After a reload all the values are different again (because the seeds change).

Comment: I was afraid of this. Seeding the random number generator is a good idea, but it severely reduces the 'randomness' of `generateRandom()`. **Not your fault by the way.** This basically turns this function into a hash function with unknown properties, due to the usage of an undocumented random generator.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I totally agree with you. This is not a real random value anymore. Nevertheless I also use the word "random" instead of "pseudo random". For security things like passwords ect. this is not acceptable. But for things like creating random exampels for tests this is good enough I think. It depends on the puropse I think. But this is **not random anymore**. You are right.

Comment: Well, I guess we agree. My problem is that there's no way of characterizing the output. user11209806 want unqiue values, but this cannot garantee that in any way. A hashing algorithm has know properties. Example: [MD5](http://www.fastsum.com/support/md5-checksum-utility-faq/md5-hash.php): "Non-discoverability: Every pair of nonidentical files will translate into a completely different hash value, even if the two files differ only by a single bit. Using today's technology, it is not possible to discover a pair of files that translate to the same hash value.", and it's MD5!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware hmm, I see your point. I didn't even think about that. The thing about hashes is that you will have the exact same result *every time*. I think this is wrong for this question. But the only argument for my solution is the same as before: For someting like tests it's good enough. Maybe you could compare hashing with the ``rand()`` function? Then you could also exchange the ``rand()`` function with something better (``random_int()`` is cryptographically secure)

Comment: Well, user11209806 seems happy with your answer, so who am I to complain? I just can't get over the abuse the random number generator is put through here. Poor generator, forced to not be random.

Comment: user11209806 is happy but you're not. This is enough reason for me to discuss :)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I updated my answer. It uses ``random_int()`` now. Can you live with this solution? :D

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a while. Well, you didn't use `srand()` anymore to fixate the random numbers, you're using a static variable now, so that's better, but it does look overly complicated. You have two lengths: `$len` and `$length`, which is what? And you reuse the key `$length.$type.$gen.$i` three times, why not assign this to a `$randomsKey` variable?

Comment: Well, Well, 50% happy :/ The new method for some reason doesn't work for me. The first one did, but as I want to use this method to bypass an ISP filter,  Now it sending the same fix random for all the emails I send in the same time. it's not just fixed per 1 email.

Comment: @user11209806 hmm, weird. Can you provide some example code wich uses the ``generateRandom()`` function and does not work? I tested my code and my given example with the ``var_dump``s is still the same as the old example. @KIKOSoftware I think we're getting into personal taste now :D I like the ``$length.$type.$gen.$i``. The ``$randomsKey`` gives the feel of an array which uses one key. The ``$length.$type.$gen.$i`` is also an array with one key but it "feels like multiple keys". In my taste it is more clear to read. ``$len`` is a temporary variable, I keep them short. Normally only one letter

Comment: @miile7 The code is running in Php 7.++ environment, I tested it's 100% good. But The app where I'm doing modifications is php 5..  so this is why random_int isn't working right ?

Comment: @user11209806 Oh damn, I didn't pay attention to this. I tested with PHP 7.1. ``random_int()`` is added with PHP 7. There is a workaround [here on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.random-int.php#119670)

Comment: @miile7 will the new solution allow me to fix my new issue ? Look I will explain a bit more. I Put this tag in my App, to send bulk-mail. Now the fix random is working but, it will send the same Fixed random in Each email . I need only to fix the random inside one email, then, that change on others. I hope you get my idea ..

Comment: @user11209806 The new version is now working like the old one (but more secure and I think more memory consuming). For your Idea I think using a function doesn't make sense. I'd use your initial ``generateRandom()`` function and save the return value into a variable. You can then use this variable in your email text. Otherwise it is getting very complicated. You could make the ``$randoms`` global and then reset it to an array after the email has finished. But the variable way is a lot easier and just better.